# Specifying default wait timeout in .NET named pipes

Tags: .net, winapi, named-pipes, namedpipeserverstream

I am working with NamedPipeServerStreams in C# where our clients will be using the Win32 CreateFile and WaitNamedPipe methods to establish connections.

Previously our server was also Win32 and was specifying the 'DefaultTimeOut' as part of the construction of the pipe when calling CreateNamedPipe().

From what I have read/seen, my understanding is that the clients then inherit this timeout value and use it when making calls to WaitNamedPipe.

Microsoft's MSDN documentation for [CreateNamedPipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has the following description for the DefaultTimeOut parameter -

> *nDefaultTimeOut [in] The default time-out value, in milliseconds, if
>   the WaitNamedPipe function specifies NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT. Each
>   instance of a named pipe must specify the same value.*

When changing to use the .NET NamedPipeServerStream there seems to be no way of passing this default timeout value into the constructor (or otherwise) and my clients are now regularly timing out on the WaitNamedPipe semaphore, where they were not previously. Without changing all our clients to specify their own timeouts which we'd like to avoid, I can't seem to find a way of doing this in .NET. Surely the .NET NamedPipe code is just wrapping the Win32 API underneath?

Comment: I'm sure the .NET code is just wrapping the Win32 API, and I'm sure it's a thin wrapper.  But as is typical with much of .NET, the rich complexity of the Win32 API is hidden and unavailable to you.  I've found this to be very true in particular with named pipes.  .NET is really rather incomplete.

Comment: So it seems, but if existing clients out there are relying on this default timeout value it seems very strange for it to not be accessible at all in .NET!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all else fails you could always call `CreateNamedPipe` via P/Invoke, specifying the default timeout you want just as you did in your Win32 server,  and then use the `NamedPipeServerStream` ctor overload which takes a `SafePipeHandle`, to wrap it.

The rest of your .NET server code wouldn't need to change.